# SQL 2008 R2 - How to grant stored procedure access read access to a table

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I wish to grant a stored procedure read access to a table in SQL Server 2008 R2

I will then grant a user access only to the stored procedure, not to the table itself.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grant EXEC access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) to the single stored procedure and no permissions to the table.

```
Grant EXECUTE On [SpName] To [Principal]
```

There is no such concept as a read permissions to a table for a stored procedure.  Stored procedure permissions are separate from other objects.  If a user has permission to run a stored procedure, they can run it no matter what it does, even if they don't have permission to the underlying objects.

Comment: How do I grant the stored procedure read access to the table?

Comment: There is no such concept.  If the user has EXEC permission on the stored procedure, then the user can run it no matter what it does, even if the user has no permissions on the underlying objects.  Permissions to stored procedures and permissions to other objects are completely independent.

Comment: Does it work the same way if the stored procedure is in a different database to the table?

Comment: I would think so, but I can't say for sure unless I would try it.  Can you try it and see what happens?

Comment: Also you can see here for more information: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic566319-146-1.aspx#bm566375.  The suggestion is to provide a view of data that the user should be allowed to see and give read-only access to that instead of the underlying table.  Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't work across databases.  That was the reason why I thought I needed to grant access to the stored procedure as I didn't realise what the problem was.   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The following article is a very detailed look at several different methods for granting permissions using stored procedures.  It's definitely worth a read.

http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html

Most of the time, [ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) will take care of permissions problems.  As long as the stored procedure and the underlying table have the same owner, the user only needs permission to `EXECUTE` the stored procedure.

In a comment to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655050/sql-2008-r2-how-to-grant-stored-procedure-access-read-access-to-a-table/7655066#7655066), you mention that the stored procedure is in a different database from the table.  You might look at [module signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102.aspx) as a method for allowing access only through the stored procedure.  Another alternative, if possible, is to create the stored procedure in the same database as the table, then grant access to users in the other database.  That way, ownership chaining will take effect.